# How to test my video memory on a 2010 13" MacBook Pro?

Tags: graphics, apple-hardware-test

I have MacBook Pro 13" Mid 2010, NVIDIA GeForce GT 320M

Recently (but right after installing OS X Lion) I've encountered artifacts on my screen. It's quite often and I can't say if the problem came from Lion (which brought me also problems with sleeping and few freezes, which I never had on Snow Leopard)

So is there any good way how to test my graphics card? or just it's video memory?

Comment: There is a known problem with the mid 2010 15" MacBook Pro's which has a bugged NVidia driver in Lion. I am not sure if this problem is related.

Comment: @Diago can you please attach link so we can find out?

Comment: Apple support article discussing the issue with the 15" MacBook: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4086

Comment: FYI. When I posted that link last night in chat there was no solution, since Apple has released a driver update which I will be testing tonight.

Comment: thanks Diaglo, I'm interested in your tests results, can I watch some info source?

Comment: The only way to truly test is by playing games, which is what I will do tonight. However, the update is specific to the 15" MacBook, and the 330M card in it as far as I know.

Comment: Having the same problem on my 13" MBP. Pretty sure Lion didn't cause it, I upgraded right on the release date and am only seeing the problem since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

MBP 13" 2010 with NVidia GT320M uses shared video memory, so any ram test would be sufficient. My recommendation is to test using [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/). If there are problems - try removing one of the sims and run with half of your memory.

Comment: OK, so that's test of memory. And to test the graphic card itself? what am I supposed to use?